# Any issues known when installing via docker image?

Tags: installation

I have installed Bitnami CiviCRM Stack 5.5.3-0, containing CiviCRM, Drupal, MySQL, Apache ... 
It works like a charm, at least the are no obvious issues for me - ok, im a complete beginner regarding Civicrm.
Are the any drawbacks known (e.g. updating single components) doing the installation in that way?